# FAQ anchor tags do not push questions to the top due to lack of space at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a FAQ page with about 30 questions in a click on question to expand answer kind of format. All of them have anchor tags because we want to be able to direct users to that specific question. The first ten questions work fine. When I click on the link to the question (Eg: www.faqs.com#Question5), question 5 lines up at the top of the page.

However, the last 10 questions do not come to the top. The page scrolls to the bottom and stops. I can see that the page is trying to push the question to the top but because of the lack of white space below it is unable to do so. I do not want to add extra white space at the bottom but is there a way to make all the anchor tags work in a way that it pushes the questions to the top? I hope the scenario is clear. Unfortunately I am not allowed to point to the page or I would have. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You can only pull your pants up so far.

Comment: Haha. That's a good way to look at it.

Comment: You could make the page longer with JS, but I think that would look weird (big chunk of white space at the bottom of your page.)

Comment: @coopersita: That's precisely why I don't want to make the page longer with white space. Looking for an alternative.